# Scala: Iterate for multiple records of a hive table

Tags: scala

I have a `val nameAgeData` defined where the source is a hive table. and the output of `val nameAgeData` looks like:

```
+----------+
|  name_age|
+----------+
|   john_15|
|    ron_12|
+----------+
```

I am trying to call another function and execute for each of those values:

```
val nameAgeList= nameAgeData.collect.toList
nameAgeList.foreach  ( id =>
          executeData(name = name,
          name_and_age = id,
          city = city)
        )
```

But this is throwing error.
Any suggestion please what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `nameAgeData` value seems to be a Spark `DataFrame`, so `nameAgeList` is a `List[Row]`.
You have to extract your data from the `Row`, ie:

```
val nameAgeList: List[String] = nameAgeData.collect.toList.map{r:Row => r.getAs[String]("name_age")}
```